# Combining Promise with Events

Tags: javascript, events, promise, dom-events, es6-promise

How should a Promise async function be done combining with event?

```
function f() {
  return promisedFunction().then(event => {
    let buf = '';
    event.on('data', data => {
      buf += data.toString()
    });
    event.on('end', () => {
      return buf;
    });
    // how should I return buf here so that the promise would resolve fine?
  });
}
```

Comment: `event` can't be an event. Surely it is an 'emittter' - something that emits events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those few situations where you can't avoid creating a new promise. You'd do that in `then` and return it:

```
function f() {
  return promisedFunction().then(event => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let buf = '';
      event.on('data', data => {
        buf += data.toString()
      });
      event.on('end', () => {
        resolve(buf);
      });
      event.on(/*...presumably there's an error condition?...*/, () => {
        reject(/*..details of error..*/);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Easily 90% of the time, you already have a promise to work with (and one of the most common errors with promise is creating them when you don't have to), but you don't have one you can use to wait for the events in your example.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to set buf to a `new Buffer` and concat to it instead of converting it to a string at each stage.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Oh, absolutely. But that's not what the question was about, and we don't really know what `event `is.

Comment: Nevermind, my bad, I didn't see the original question did this too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @BenjaminGruenbaum and T.J. Crowder. The ones on Buffer is very useful too.

Comment: I typically push the buffers into an array and then call `Buffer.concat` on the array of buffers.